# Login route with cookies AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I'm doing login to my site with angularjs. My code: HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username">

        <input type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" >

        <button type="submit" ng-click="login()">Sign in</button>
```

My JS:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'login.html'
        })
        .when('/dashboard', {
            resolve: {
                "check": function($location, $rootScope) {
                    if(!$rootScope.valueCookie) {
                        $location.path('/');
                    }
                }
            },
            templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});

     $scope.login = function() {
            $cookieStore.put('cookie', someSessionObj);
        $rootScope.valueCookie = $cookieStore.get('cookie');
        $location.path('/dashboard');
        }
```

What i try to do is cookies resolve. When cookies are in browser - after click signin, and we are in "dashboard.html", after refresh page there's still "dashboard.html". My code don't work, if i refresh page on "dashboard.html" it moves me to login. Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: Does the cookies in question have the httponly flag set? If so, you cannot read it using javascript.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen Probably after refresh page the $rootScope is reset too. Have you any idea to resolve this problem? or otherwise login with cookies.

Comment: The best advice I can come up with is pretty much to only let the backend handle the cookies.

Comment: $cookieStore is deprecated, use $cookies instead

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with

```
if(!$rootScope.valueCookie) {
     $location.path('/');
}
```

Whenever you refresh the page, your `$rootScope` will not have `valueCookie`.
To make it work, write below code in your run function.

```
app.config(function() {
   // your code
}).run(function($rootScope, $cookieStore){
   $rootScope.valueCookie = $cookieStore.get('cookie');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On dashboard page you can write a `ng-init` function

Dashboard.html

```
<div ng-init="myFunction()">


</div>
```

And in dashboard controller you can do this

```
$scope.myFunction = function(){

$scope.valueCookie = $cookieStore.get('cookie');
}
```

So whenever you refresh dashboard page init function will be called and cookies value will be stored in `$scope` variable